# How to write a dll from an empty project in visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, dll

The reason why it should be **empty** is because I need to write it in C:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951516/what-good-ides-are-availble-for-c/951582#951582

But how to write a dll from scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows DLL are written using this skeleton

```
#include <windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
  __in  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  __in  DWORD fdwReason,
  __in  LPVOID lpvReserved
){
   switch(fdwReason){
      case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
           break;
      case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
           break;
      case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
           break;
      case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
           break;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

See here on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583(VS.85).aspx) for this and an example of it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682596(VS.85).aspx). [Here](http://logix4u.net/Programming/vc++/A_Tutorial_on_creating_DLLs_with_VC++.html) is a tutorial on creating a DLL. A more in-depth tutorial can be found [here](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/4877).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: How to write a dll that can be used in *nix environment?

Comment: I think you should post a separate question for this as the context is very different from writing a dll in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7):

Use **File -> New project -> Visual C++ -> Win32 project**
Select application type **DLL** and additional options **Empty project**.

**Edit:**

To get a C template the easiest way is to not check **Empty project** and then convert the project:

1. Rename the CPP-files to C (right
   click on them in the solution
   explorer)
2. Remove StdAfx.cpp
3. In Project -> {project} Properties change
   Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled headers
   You can choose to not use pre-compiled headers or you can change it to Create new ones.
4. Build your project
5. Add the meat to the template

For pointers on how to write the DLL code google for [dll sample code](http://www.google.com/search?q=dll+sample+code)

Comment: No, sorry. I guess I'm too used to answer the question on how to get started. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Why not rename StdAfx.cpp to C and enable Precompiled headers?